# How to find recursive dates in php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

I have a data like this:

```
$date = '01-01-2014';
$time = '15:20:00';
$location = 'New Delhi';
$recursive = '1';
.........................
.........................  // other data
```

$recursive = 1 means weekly and 2 means monthly.

Now what i am tring to do is if recursive type is weekly then add 7 days into it till 3 months and if recursive type is monthly then add 1 month into it till 3 months.

> Exa:1 $date = '01-01-2014' and $recursive = '1'

Means in above example `$recursive` is weekly, so get a recursive date for January, February and March.
So the expected results are:

```
01-01-2014, 08-01-2014, 15-01-2014, 22-01-2014, 29-01-2014 (recursiive date in january)
05-02-2014, 12-02-2014, 19-02-2014, 26-02-2014 (recursiive date in february)
05-03-2014, 12-03-2014, 19-03-2014, 26-03-2014 (recursiive date in march)
```

> Exa 2: $date = `15-04-2014` and $recursive = `1` then get recursive date for April, May and June.

output:

```
15-04-2014,22-04-2014,29-04-2014 (recursive date in april)
06-05-2014,13-05-2014,20-05-2014,27-05-2014 (recursive date in may)
03-06-2014,10-06-2014,17-06-2014,24-06-2014 (recursive date in june)
```

> Exa 3 : $date = `01-01-2014` and $recursive = `2` then get recursive date for April, May and June.

This is monthly recursive, means add 1 month into it.

output:

```
01-01-2014 
01-02-2014 (recursiive date in february)
01-03-2014 (recursiive date in march)
```

then i want to insert these dates with other data into database table.

so how to achive above things? should i write logic in php or use mysql query for it?

Thanks in advance.

SIDENOTE: currently i am using [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632209/recursive-logic-in-php-mysql). but now i am trying to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solve it.

```
$date = '01-01-2014';
$location = 'New Delhi';

$start = strtotime("+2 months", strtotime($date));  //start date
$end_date = date("Y-m-t", $start);   // last day of end month
$end = strtotime($end_date);   //last date

/* if recursion type is weekly */
if($json['recurrence'] == "1")
{
    for($dd=$start; $dd<=$end;)
    {
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $dd);
        $data[] = array(
            'date' => $new_date,
            'location' => $location
        );
        $dd = strtotime("+7 day", $dd);  // add 7 days
    }
}

if($json['recurrence'] == "2")
{
    for($dd=$start; $dd<=$end;)
    {
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $dd);
        $data[] = array(
            'date' => $new_date,
            'location' => $location
        );
        $dd = strtotime("+1 month", $dd);  //add 1 month
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

so basically what you want to do is something like this.

```
//you have to have a default time zone set.. so i just did this you should already have it in your .ini file
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = '01-01-2014';
$time = '15:20:00';
$location = 'New Delhi';
$recursive = '1';

//set your start date and end date
$startdate = date_create($date);
$enddate = date_create($date);
$enddate = date_add($enddate,date_interval_create_from_date_string("3 months"));

//set the interval string
if($recursive == '1'){
  $str = "7 days";
} else {
  $str = "1 month";
}
function recursivefunc($str, $start, $end){
  //if the start is equal or bigger than end pop out.
  $s = date_format($start,"Y/m/d");
  $e = date_format($end,"Y/m/d");
  if(strtotime($s) >= strtotime($e)){
    return 1;
  }
  echo date_format($start,"Y/m/d"), '<br>'; //print out the starting date for each loop
  $newDate = date_add($start,date_interval_create_from_date_string($str)); //increment the start
  recursiveFunc($str, $newDate, $end); //call the function again

}
recursiveFunc($str, $startdate, $enddate); // initial call to the function
```